# Parent or ParentNode / Class Selector

Tags: javascript, performance, interface, frontend

Class selector is not working and how do I always get the class that I apply the function in particular and not the first, because the items have the same class if the selector by class work it will take the first class and not in the element I'm applying.

**HTML**

```
<li class="space_form">
    <label>
        Nome*
        <input type="text" class="no-empty" name="Nome" value="Nome" onFocus="formEmptyLeft(this);clearText(this)" onBlur="formEmptyLeft(this);clearText(this)" />
        <div class="campo_vazio-left">*Preenchimento do campo obrigatório</div>                                                                                     
    </label>
</li>

<li class="fright">
    <label>
        Sobrenome*
        <input type="text" class="no-empty" name="Sobrenome" value="Sobrenome" onFocus="formEmptyRight(this);clearText(this)" onBlur="formEmptyRight(this);clearText(this)" />
        <div class="campo_vazio-right">*Preenchimento do campo obrigatório</div>                                                                                                                                    
    </label>
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function formEmptyLeft()
{
    var input = document.getElementByClass('no-empty');

    if(input.value.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementByClass('campo_vazio-left').style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementByClass('no-empty').classList.add('form_invalido');              
    }
    else {
        document.getElementByClass('campo_vazio-left').style.display = 'none'; 
        document.getElementByClass('no-empty').classList.remove('form_invalido');                   
    }       
}   

function formEmptyRight()
{
    var input = document.getElementByClass('no-empty');

    if(input.value.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementByClass('campo_vazio-right').style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementByClass('no-empty').classList.add('form_invalido');              
    }
    else {
        document.getElementByClass('campo_vazio-right').style.display = 'none'; 
        document.getElementByClass('no-empty').classList.remove('form_invalido');                   
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript code you added in **your other question** was incomplete - at least this is what the chrome console tells (see screenshot).

[image: Overview of errors]

```
<input type="text" class="no-empty name_field" name="Nome" value="Nome" 
      onFocus="formEmptyLeft();clearText()"
      onBlur="formEmptyLeft();clearText()" />
```

Above the `clearText()` function is fired - but the code above has no clearText function.

In the second screenshot you see the result of these lines

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('no-empty');
if(input.value.length == 0)
```

You forgot to add the `document.getElementsByClassName('no-empty')[0];` and now you have an array instead of an input element.

[image: Error location]

Here you can see that `document.getElementsByClassName('no-empty');` returns an array. You forgot to add the [0] to access the first element of the array.

[image: result of your code returns an array]

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, I am sure you ment `document.getElementsByClassName` instead of `document.getElementByClass`.

On the other hand, consider that `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a set of elements, so you should do something like this `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[1].value`.

There is plenty of info about this subject, are you stuck in a specific problem ?

Comment: the first element is 0 so document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0]

Comment: Still not working, I dont know why but the getElementByClassName does not work.

Comment: getElementsByClassName ... elementsssss

Comment: sure, i just put [1] as an example,  thanks for clarification anyway ;)

Comment: @Neylor Zaurisio: why do you use "this" as a parameter ? i dont see where do you use it on the function ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I think you just want to be more specific with your css selector.
So you could use a querySelector eg...

document.querySelector('.space_form .no-empty');

Which will find a 'no-empty' class below a 'space_form' class.

Although this requires IE8 or above I think so may be a problem if you are supporting really old browsers.